# How do I get ctrl-c to interrupt a script running via rvm do?

Tags: ruby, rvm

If I run a ruby script by typing something like this:

rvm 1.9.3 do ruby myscript.rb

My script runs using that ruby, but if it's executing and I hit ctrl-c, the script doesn't get the signal.  I have to hit ctrl-c a second time.

This is fine from the command line, but if I now wrap that whole thing in a script, there isn't a chance for a second ctrl-c.  How do I get ctrl-c to interrupt a script running via rvm do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
rvm-shell 1.9.3 -c "ruby myscript.rb"
```

if you can not get it running in any way open rvm issue => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues